# rerun scripts and rerender styles after each route change in SPA's? (Vue / React / Angular)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, vue.js, single-page-application

I am building a scripts and styles manager for a WordPress based single page application. Initially I thought it would be enough just to load missing scripts on each route change. But now I realize some scripts have to be run again on each route/page change like  scripts that track interaction with the content of each route/page. Also you have to keep the order of the included styles. Some styles have to be rerendered after including the new missing ones to achieve the desired result.

Are there any established strategies how to handle this general problem with SPA's?

As I understand it now you can only rerender all styles on each route change if there are any new styles to include. And for scripts you would have to predefine scripts which have to be rerendered on each route change. But this sounds way to complicated and might destroy all the performance advances of a SPA.

Answer (score 0):

could you show an example why you need that, because if you want to update your styles just add them with script, if you want to add different .css/.sass./.scss etc files on different routes, you have several options: 1. pass them through props, 2. import all possible styles but use only one, that you need. anyway there is context in react more: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

if you want to change some styles instead of whole files, just add different classes on different routes, of course you can do that with script
everything depends on why do you need that.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer. But the question is rather abstract and more about general strategies not a specific implementation. In a WordPress app you don't have control over all the scripts and styles. As I understand it now you can only rerender all styles on each route change if there are any new styles to include. And for scripts you would have to predefine scripts which have to be rerun on each route change. But this sounds way to complicated and might destroy all the performance advances of a SPA.

Comment: @TechNomad you always can request new styles from server and pass them into component through props

Comment: I know I can. That's not the issue. The question is not about a particular script or style but about general strategies for how to implement this functionality fully automated for all registered scripts and styles.